# How to get the loop working

Tags: java, loops

I am having trouble with getting a loop to work in my code, so if the user says No it will bring them back to the first question they have to answer with Yes.

```
 System.out.println("Adventurer soliders need your aid in Silverkeep can you deliver supplys to them? ");

 String choice;
 System.out.print("So can you deliver the supplys to them? ");
 choice = in.next();

 if (choice.equals("Yes"))
    System.out.println("Thank you so much, he are the supplys they need.");
 else if (choice.equals("No"))
    System.out.println("But these soliders lives depend on these supplys! You must help us.");
```

So if they say No it will bring them back up to the System.out.print line.

```
System.out.println("Adventurer soliders need your aid in Silverkeep can you deliver supplys to them? ");
while (run) {
    String choice;
    System.out.print("So can you deliver the supplys to them? ");
    choice = in.next();

    if (choice.equals("Yes"))
        System.out.println("Thank you so much, he are the supplys they need.");

    else if(choice.equals("No"))
        System.out.println("But these soliders lives depend on these supplys! You must help us.");
    run = true;
}
```

When I try and run the code above it just spams the console with "So can you deliver the supplies to them?"

So where did I go wrong.. I tried multiple things but no luck.

Comment: How do you declare 'in'?

Comment: `run = true;` is always true. Infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

You aren't putting { } around the things after your if and else so it only does the very next statement. `run=true;` is always happening.

Comment: If he is not putting {} around, then code has to run infinite time because run = true; will happen always

Comment: But he said "spams out"... shouldn't the in.next() be blocking at least?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code now,

```
    System.out.println("Adventurer soliders need your aid in Silverkeep can you deliver     supplys to them? ");

    while (run) {
        String choice;
        System.out.print("So can you deliver the supplys to them? ");
        choice = in.next();

        if (choice.equals("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Thank you so much, he are the supplys they need.");
            run = false;
        } else if (choice.equals("No")) {
            System.out.println("But these soliders lives depend on these supplys! You must help us.");
            run = true;
        }
    }
```

you forget to initialize the run value with the boolean value false;

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***do........while*** loop as you want to decide on the basis of user selection to whether you have to prompt the question again or not. but at first go you have to ask from the user........

System.out.println("Adventurer soliders need your aid in Silverkeep can you deliver     supplys to them? ");

```
do {
    String choice;
    System.out.print("So can you deliver the supplys to them? ");
    choice = in.next();

    if (choice.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you so much, he are the supplys they need.");
        run = false;
    } else if (choice.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("But these soliders lives depend on these supplys! You must help us.");
        run = true;
    }
}while (run)
```

and you need to declare run

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
do{
    //Your code
}while(choice.equals("No"))
```